# itextsharp: how to move the datatable?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

as you can see my data table is a little too much on the right, how do i move it more to the left? please include answer in vb.net
[alt text http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/3661/fullscreencapture121520.png](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/3661/fullscreencapture121520.png)

Comment: Can you add the code you used to create the datatable and insert it into the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a `PdfPTable` you can explicitly set the position of the table using the table's `WriteSelectedRows()` method.

[Here's](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/examples/Chap1009.cs) a C# example
Documentation on `WriteSelectedRows` (such as it exists) can be found at the [sourceforge tutorial](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch10.html).

The links I provided are in C#.  I've seen very little iTextSharp code in VB.NET but ran [this class](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/examples/Chap1009.cs) through the [DeveloperFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) C# to VB.NET converter and results looked good to me.  If you haven't already, you might want to bookmark the DeveloperFusion converter site.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to adjust the margins. i'm guessing you're looking at the default.

Here's a [simple iTextSharp](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Java/Creating-Simple-PDF-Files-With-iTextSharp/) example that shows how to manipulate margins.